# Expo warning when running on android emulator

Tags: windows, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I have been building a react-native app using Expo. It has been running fine on the android emulator, but suddenly it will no longer load on the emulator. Here is the following error message:

```js
Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for C:\User\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-45.0.0.json: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
```

I am using Android Studio and developing on a Windows OS.

I have tried updating my expo-cli, using expo-doctor to fix my dependencies, deleting my package.lock file and reinstalling my modules, and clearing my expo cache. I have also tried clearing the data on my Android Studio device. None of these things have helped.

Also, my app runs fine in the expo web browser, so it is not a fatal error in my actual source code.

Any ideas about what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be resolved by clearing the react-native packager cache.

Run: `expo start --clear`

You can add this to your package for future reference as well:

```
"start:clear": "expo start --clear",
```

Check the expo cli docs for additional info as well:
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/expo-cli/

Comment: This worked. I also had to create the missing schema and add it to my expo directory. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad this worked for you.